# Xcode error "Conflicting types" running a C code for a very simple function

Tags: c, xcode, executable, memset

I am trying to run to following function as part of a bigger project:

```
#include <memory.h>

void bzero(char *s, int n)
{
    memset (s, 0, n);
}
```

I am getting the following error: 
"Conflicting types for 'bzero'"

I don't understand the problem, since the entire projects works fine on Linux. So I am actually trying to transfer it onto Mac and to create and executable file using Xcode, but it won't even built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your system there is already a `bzero` function (a legacy POSIX function that is now removed) with a different prototype. Name your function differently like `my_bzero`.

Comment: Thanks man! That worked. Maybe you can also help me with another recurring build error that I have in every single file of my project.. It keeps giving me the message "control reaches the end of non-void function". I know that it means that the function MIGHT reach the end without returning anything, or at least it means that the compiler thinks it may happen. However, again I have run this project for years now on linux no problem. It there a way to bypass that? Like maybe just 'return 0'?

Comment: @GuyTal You had run this project for many years without warnings enabled in your compiler. Yes, add a `return 0;` statement at the end of the function where you got this warning (assuming the function returns an arithmetic type value). If you want to continue the discussion on this other topic I suggest you to open a new question with an example code.

Comment: I stuck with `qsort`

Answer (score 0):

[`bzero`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bzero.html) is a non-standard C function used in system programming and that's causing the conflict on your system. It has prototype

```
void bzero(void *s, size_t n);
```